# Why fopen doesn't work in anonymous function (Closure)?

Tags: php, laravel

I don't understand why this code works :

```
$file = fopen('/opt/test.csv', 'w'); 
fclose($file);
```

while this code doesn't work :

```
$callback = function() use($elements, $columns) {
    $file = fopen('/opt/test.csv', 'w');
    fclose($file);
};
```

No error but it does not save the file in the repository.
Have you an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Do you call `$callback` somewhere with suitable parameters as arguments?

Comment: Yup, in fact I call this function two times, one time to stream the response (download in the browser) and another time to just store this file in filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to replicate the failure to write to a file using essentially the same code as above. Added some `fwrite` calls to indicate success of callback and prove file creation was successful.

```
$filepath=__DIR__ . '/test.csv';

$elements=array('Carbon','Nitrogen','Oxygen');
$columns=array('corinthian','doric','ionic','tuscan','egyptian','aeolic','persian');

$callback = function() use( $elements, $columns ) {
    global $filepath;
    
    $file = fopen( $filepath, 'w' );
    fwrite( $file, implode(',', $elements ) . PHP_EOL );
    fwrite( $file, implode(',', $columns ) . PHP_EOL );
    fclose( $file );
};

call_user_func( $callback, $elements, $columns );
```

The above works OK and yields a CSV file, in the same directory as the running script, with the following content:

```
Carbon,Nitrogen,Oxygen
corinthian,doric,ionic,tuscan,egyptian,aeolic,persian
```